# Test with MockMvc in Java / Spring Boot - header "Authorization"

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockmvc

How can i test an endpoint with authorization header with a user context?

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/endpoint")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", authorizationToken(APP_AUTHORIZATION)))
        .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is2xxSuccessful());
```

I tried to do this, but it didn't work.

```
private String buildToken(@Nonnull ApiClient.JwtData data) throws JsonProcessingException {
    final var token = JWT.create()
            .withSubject(data.getUserId())
            .withIssuedAt(new Date())
            .withClaim("name", data.getUsername())
            .withClaim("fullname", data.getUserFullName())
            .withClaim("userid", data.getUserId())
            .withClaim("locale", Objects.requireNonNullElse(data.getLocale(), DEFAULT_LOCALE));
    final var authsMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    token.withClaim("authorities", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(authsMap));
    return token.sign(Algorithm.HMAC256(SECRET));
}

protected String authorizationToken(String... authorities) throws JsonProcessingException {
    final var jwtData = new ApiClient.JwtData("USER_ID", "USER_NAME", "USER_FULLNAME"
            , "locale", "USER_AUTHORITIES", "US-EN", authorities);
    return buildToken(jwtData);
}
```